# Как правильно тестировать UI через проекты тестирования в VS?

Tags: c#, winforms, test-automation

Прочитал документацию и не понял как пользоваться UI тестами.

В особенности, как правильно запускать приложение, что бы тест работал.

Пробовал так: Запускаю запись теста, перехожу в папку с программой и запускаю EXE, что-то делаю и закрываю программу.

При запуске теста ничего не произошло и вылетела ошибка.

Пробовал и так: Запускал запись теста, запускал проект через F5, проделывал некотоыре действия и закрывал тест.

И опять при тестировании вылетела ошибка...

Собственно вопрос:

Что я делаю не правильно? Ведь у меня при проигрывании записанного теста, всегда вылетает ошибка...

Как я понимаю, тест не запускает даже мое WinForm приложение.

Comment: тестирование UI не является модульным тестом, это можно назвать тестом интеграционным(сомнительно). Более правильным названием будут: функциональные тесты, либо же тесты приёмки(acceptance)